# How to extract [no tags words] with xpath?

Tags: xpath

```
<body>
    <p>First First First</p>
    Second Second Second
    <p>Third Third Third</p>
    Fourth Fourth Fourth
</body>
```

This is an xml code, how can I extract "Second Second Second" with xpath?

Comment: Using "/body/text()" can get a result "Second Second Second  Fourth Fourth Fourth",but how can I extract them independently?

Comment: You could use `/body/text()[1]`, but that will most probably, depending on your XML formatting, return only whitespace (e.g. the line break after `<body>`).

Depending on what you really want (e.g. extracting the text after the first <p>), different solutions are possible, including the answer given by Roman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following XPath expressions:

- to get the text node right after the first `<p>`:

  ```
  //body/p[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
  ```
- to get the text node right after the second `<p>`:

  ```
  //body/p[2]/following-sibling::text()[1]
  ```

Comment: It works,but the html code is but that simple,I cannot just matching 'Second' to extract what I want.
Actually I want to get an array of these no tags words,some workaround here?

Comment: @zjutkz Then you have to redefine your problem. Do you want to extract everything between the two `<p>` tags? Or every body text, one by one?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Every body text,one by one

Comment: @zjutkz You should edit your question then to make that more clear. Also, as "one by one" requires an algorithmic logic, you should perhaps include a programming language in which you want to use this (XSLT would also be OK).

Comment: @zjutkz, but that what `//body/text()` exactly returns. Text nodes one by one. Can be easily processed by some programming language, e.g. PHP

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, but it returned "Second Second Second  Fourth Fourth Fourth" using WebMagic(a web crawler framework for Java),two nodes are combined in one string.
Maybe I made the wrong express of this question,I want to get two strings,"Second Second Second" and "Fourth Fourth Fourth".

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, OK thx,I will use PHP or Python to finish this job.